# What would the collapse of a white dwarf to a neutron star look it

Tags: supernova, neutron-star, white-dwarf

It’s hypothesised that some white dwarves, when raised in mass above the Chandrasekhar limit, will instead of producing a type 1A supernova, will instead collapse into a Neutron star.
What would this look like? How bright would it be? How strong would the Neutrino flux be?
Could you end up with a neutron star lighter then is lower possible limit for neutron stars produced by type II supernovae.

Comment: see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/why-does-the-chandrasekhar-limit-affect-white-dwarfs-differently